# spark-submit process does not terminate after job completion automatically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I'm submitting a pyspark job using spark-submit in client mode on yarn.

```
spark-submit   \
          --name $APP_NAME \
          --master yarn \
          --deploy-mode client \
          --num-executors 16 \
          --executor-cores 1 \
          --driver-memory 6g \
          --executor-memory 2g \
          
          --py-files myfile.py
            --version 2.3
```

The job completes successfully and I can verify that in Spark history as well as from Yarn.
Even after Job completion I still see the spark-submit process running and it doesn't terminate.

I wanted to have a job status back from my calling program  which invokes the submit job (Jenkins using publish over ssh plugin). Is there any way to make sure that the spark-submit process terminates with proper exit code after finishing job?

I've tried stopping spark context and putting exit status at the end of python script. This still doesn't work.

```
sc.stop()
sys.exit(0)
```

This happens randomly mostly for long running jobs.
I don't see any issue for Cluster mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can write unix shell script and then you are able to check starus of command via $?

```
  spark-submit   \
      --name $APP_NAME \
      --master yarn \
      --deploy-mode client \
      --num-executors 16 \
      --executor-cores 1 \
      --driver-memory 6g \
      --executor-memory 2g \
      
      --py-files myfile.py
        --version 2.3
```

then you can check status and add your conditions

```
   if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
       echo 'Success'
    else
       'fail'
   fi
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change conf `--deploy-mode` to `cluster` and try again.